# Unable to set cookies on server side with Sveltekit

Tags: cookies, sveltekit

the title speaks for itself: From one moment to another, I am unable to set cookies from the server page of my Sveltekit project.

In the +page.server.js of my page I have an action in which I am setting a cookie with the `set` function. After that, when reloading the page, I am trying to retrieve the cookie with the `get` function inside the `load` function, but the cookie is undefined. I am quite convinced that it is not set at all, but I don't know why.

```js
export const load = async ({ cookies }) => {
    const myCookie = cookies.get('myCookie');
}

export const actions = {
    default: async ({ cookies }) => {
        //stuff
        cookies.set('myCookie', true);
        throw redirect(303, '/');
    }
}
```

I specify that this is a procedure I have already done in other projects and it has always worked. What could be the problem? Thank you for your help.

UPDATE:

I don't know if it helps, but I want to specify that I am using Pocketbase and that a cookie is set in the hook.server.js of the project, which I can see in the browser and works correctly:

```js
export async function handle({ event, resolve }) {
    event.locals.pb = new PocketBase('http://127.0.0.1:8090');
    event.locals.pb.authStore.loadFromCookie(event.request.headers.get('cookie') || '');

    if (event.locals.pb.authStore.isValid) {
        event.locals.user = serializeNonPOJOs(event.locals.pb.authStore.model);
    } else {
        event.locals.user = undefined;
    }

    const response = await resolve(event, {
        transformPageChunk: ({ html }) => minify(html, minification_options)
    })
    response.headers.set('set-cookie', event.locals.pb.authStore.exportToCookie({ secure: false }));

    return response
}
```

Comment: Can you see the cookie in the browser? Does it have the correct `path`?

Comment: No, it does not appear, as if I had not set it up at all.

Comment: (You probably should not set cookies via `response.headers.set`, `handle` should also provide cookies in the event.)

Comment: Can you confirm that the action with `cookies.set` runs without error?

Comment: @H.B. Can you elaborate more? Excuse me but I am not very experienced... Also, I can absolutely confirm that there are no errors when running the action.

Comment: I suspected that setting the cookies via `response.headers` might interfere with previously set cookies, but that appears to be not the case. It appends another header which should set another cookie. Can't see what is wrong with this code if both operations work on different cookies.

Comment: I have already written a detailed answer on this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76854455/cant-set-cookies-inside-a-load-function/76893250#76893250