# Can't set cookies inside a load function

Tags: javascript, cookies, svelte, sveltekit, cookiestore

I'm fairly new to Svelte Kit and I am trying to set a cookie in the load function of my `+page.server.js`.

Here is the code I have tried:

```
export const load = ({ cookies }) => {

    cookies.set("username", "foo", {
        secure : false,
        maxAge : 60 * 60 * 24 * 7
    })
    
}
```

How ever the cookie doesn't get set and I verify this by opening the Application panel of the developer console to check if the cookie has been made.

I also don't get any errors for performing this action.

I can however get previously existing cookies inside the load function without any problems,
using `cookies.get()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of frustration and agony, I have figured out why my cookies wouldn't get set.

I am using pocketbase for authentication and I am handling the authentication in my `hooks.server.js` in this way:

```
import PocketBase from 'pocketbase'
import { serializeNonPOJOs } from '$lib/utils'

export const handle = async ({ event, resolve }) => {
    event.locals.pb = new PocketBase('http://localhost:8090')
    event.locals.pb.authStore.loadFromCookie(event.request.headers.get("cookie") || "")

    try {
        if (event.locals.pb.authStore.isValid) {
            await event.locals.pb.collection('users').authRefresh()
            event.locals.user = serializeNonPOJOs(event.locals.pb.authStore.model)
        }
    } catch(_) {
        event.locals.authStore.clear()
        event.locals.user = undefined
    }

    const response = await resolve(event)

    response.headers.set('set-cookie', event.locals.pb.authStore.exportToCookie({
        secure : false
    }))

    return response
}
```

The handle function runs on every request to the server and you can read more about it in the official documentation of SvelteKit: https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/hooks#server-hooks-handle

Now the issue is in this specific line of code:

```
response.headers.set('set-cookie', event.locals.pb.authStore.exportToCookie({
        secure : false
    }))
```

Here I'm using `response.headers.set()` to set my authentication cookie which is a problem as it wipes out the entire cookie list and only sets the authentication cookie

In reality I should have been doing this:

```
response.headers.append('set-cookie', event.locals.pb.authStore.exportToCookie({
        secure : false
    }))
```

This appends the authentication cookie into the cookie list instead of wiping the entire thing

After making the changes, I got the desired result:

[image: Desired outcome]

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, I couldn't reproduce, because it worked for me. I am using typescript (as should you, tbh) but this code should more or less work:

+page.server.ts

```
import type { PageServerLoad } from './$types';


export const load: PageServerLoad = ({cookies}) => {

    cookies.set("test", "val")

    return {}
}
```

I then went into my chrome browser, and sure enough:

[image: cookie, yay!]

Maybe try fiddling around with your cookie options.

PS: Maybe it's mad at you because your load function is not returning anything?

Comment: Thanks for replying,
Unfortunately returning something doesn't help the situation.

I have tried many different cookies combinations but still no change.

I'm also using pocketbase for authentication which sets the auth cookie in hooks.server.js(probably should have mentioned in the initial question) which might be causing issues.

Comment: Ah, I see. Yeah, would have probably been useful to mention. Seeing your answer, it seems obvious to me what the problem was, so in future questions, mentioning the details would be useful. Still, I'm glad you figured it out!

Comment: Yeah my bad should have mentioned it but still thanks for replying and trying to help out it was very much appreciated